# Calculating expected value when I don't know the function

Tags: statistics

> You're given a randomizing function in which $x = 1$ with probability $0.1$,
>   $x = 2$ with probability $0.3$ and $x = 3$ with $P=0.6$. Calculate the
>   expected value.

So I know how to calculate the expected value of a function by using a definite integral over a given interval of $xf(x)$ Here, though, I don't have the information of what $f(x)$ even is (the formula, I mean). How to calculate it here, then?

Answer (score 1):

No integrals required here since your randomizing function (or just random variable) is discrete. The expected value of a discrete random variable $X$ with probability function $p$, $p(x)=P(X=x)$, is simply given by
$$
{\rm E}[X]=\sum_{x: \,p(x)>0}xp(x).
$$
So to calculate the expected value just find $p(x)$ and insert in the formula above.